# Cant set UISegmentedControl to be clear

Tags: uiview, uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor

What am I doing wrong to set the segmentedControl's colour to clear, it is currently black?

```
UISegmentedControl *control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Info", @"People", @"Photos", @"Items", nil]];
    [control setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, self.frame.size.width, 40)];
    [control setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [control setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [control setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```